# React js return function recursive

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, recursive-datastructures

Hello I'm trying to print data, using recursive, this is the function:

```
function list({ data, tab }){

    if( !data || !data.length ){
        return null;
    }        

    return data.map( item => {
      <React.Fragment>
            <div className="row" key={item.id} >
                <div className="col-md-10">
                    { tab + item.name}
                </div>
                <div className="row col-md mx-auto">
                    <Link 
                        to={`/edit/${item.id}`} 
                        className="col-md px-0" 
                        title="Edit"
                    >
                        Edit
                    </Link>   
                    <button
                        className="col-md px-0"
                        onClick={ () => delete(item.id) }
                        title="Delete"
                    >
                      Delete>                                    
                    </button>   
                </div>
            </div>
            <list data={item.child} tab={tab+"\t"} />
      </React.Fragment>
    });
}
```

so the struct of data is like:

```
[
    {
     id: '0',
     name: 'name 1'
     parent: null,
     child:[{                    
            id: '4',
            name: 'name 4'
            parent: '0',
            child:[{
                    id: '3',
                    name: 'name 3'
                    parent: '4',
                    child:[{}]  
                }]                 
           },
           {                    
            id: '2',
            name: 'name 2'
            parent: '0',
            child:[{
                    id: '5',
                    name: 'name 5'
                    parent: '2',
                    child:[{}]  
                }]                 
           },
           {                    
            id: '6',
            name: 'name 6'
            parent: '0',
            child:[{}]                 
           }                           
        ]
    }
]
```

you can see that the tree is completily dinamic, so I can use recursive to solve it, but I'm getting some problem, I'm showing only  "name 1", and not all data, what can I do to get it???

Comment: Your print function `return`s before calling itself. Even if you fix that, it's not going to work though. The result of the inner `print()` call has to be part of the JSX you return. Actually, the very fact that you chose `print` as the name means your approach is wrong; the function should be called `jsx` or similar. It's not supposed to output ("print") anything, just turn the supplied tree into a JSX version.

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your code: the `if` statement is never executed because you `return` from the function beforehand. You are `return`ing inside the loop, i.e. the loop will only execute once. You also don't do anything with the return value of the recursive `print` call. It's not clear where the nested data should be rendered in relation to the parent.

Comment: @Chris G so I should remove "return" and change name's function???...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to confuse you. What I means is that the name you chose heavily suggests that you are approaching this the wrong way, and your code confirms this. Your approach is fine if it's about printing stuff in a console app, but for React and JSX, you need to turn your tree into an expression, not a bunch of print statements. You absolutely need the return though. Here's a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-nightingale-098lx?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Chris G thanks you!!! this help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this...

```
const rows = []
const data = [
    {
        id: '0',
        name: 'name 1',
        parent: null,
        child: [{
            id: '4',
            name: 'name 4',
            parent: '0',
            child: [{
                id: '3',
                name: 'name 3',
                parent: '4',
                child: [{}]
            }]
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            name: 'name 2',
            parent: '0',
            child: [{
                id: '5',
                name: 'name 5',
                parent: '2',
                child: [{}]
            }]
        },
        {
            id: '6',
            name: 'name 6',
            parent: '0',
            child: [{}]
        }]
    }
]

const Row = (item, tab) => {
    return (
        <div className="row" key={item.id}>
            <div className="col-md-10">
                {tab + item.name}
            </div>
            <div className="row col-md mx-auto">
                <Link 
                    to={`/edit/${item.id}`} 
                    className="col-md px-0" 
                    title="Edit"
                >
                    Edit
                </Link>
                <button
                    className="col-md px-0"
                    onClick={() => delete (item.id)}
                    title="Delete"
                >
                    Delete>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const print = (data, tab) => {
    data.forEach(item => {
        if (Object.keys(item).length === 0) {
            return
        }
        rows.push(Row(item, tab))

        if (item.child && item.child.length > 0) {
            print(item.child, tab + "\t")
        }
    })
}

print(data, '')
return rows
```